# add class to other non clicked element base on href tag

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#home">home</a>
<li><a href="#services">services</a>
<li><a href="#contact">contact</a>
<ul>
```

and in other part of my html some links that are pointing to the same "href"

```
<a href="#home"></a>
```

What I want to do is add a class to the li element containing an "a" element with the same href of the clicked link.

Comment: Try : http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+class+to+another+element

Comment: have you tried adding the class to the css yourself? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('li a[href="#home"]').closest("li").addClass("myclass");
```

Comment: I think he want the class on the li element

Comment: That adds to the anchor element not the li element which is the desired behavior.

Comment: meub .. i am not sure i got it straight at first. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('a[href="' + this.href + '"]').parent('li').addClass('new-class')
```